# With Rails 4.2.3 changing the behavior of where_values, how do I get valid SQL for where_values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

An `ActiveRelation` instance has `where_values`.  In Rails 4.2.2 and earlier the following code

```ruby
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :staff_picks, -> { where(staff_pick: true) }
end

puts Post.staff_picks.where_values[0].to_sql
```

for Postgresql returned

```
"posts"."staff_pick" = 't'
```

and that was correct.

Rails 4.2.3 breaks this behavior, the same code returns

```
"posts"."staff_pick" = $1
```

How do I get the same valid SQL in Rails 4.2.3 and 4.2.4?

Comment: Why do you need parts of you query as SQL string? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I need to use that SQL for a bigger more complex query.

Comment: Perhaps there is a simple way than digging into Arel interals. Did you consider using [`merge`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) for example? Can you please post a simplified example of what you actually need to do?

Comment: I think you are right. Relying on `where_values` is wrong (not my code originally).  I rewrote it with `merge`, then `to_sql`, and then strip the leading `SELECT ... ` with  `sql[sql.index('WHERE') + 6 .. -1]`. It might be not that beautiful, but it works

Answer (score 3):

This did change in Rails 4.2.3, but the original behavior, without the binding, can be obtained by updating the scope to use AREL:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :staff_picks, -> { where(arel_table[:staff_pick].eq(true)) }
end

puts Post.staff_picks.where_values[0].to_sql # => "`posts`.`staff_pick` = 1"
```

This is also backwards compatible to Rails 4.1 and Rails 3.2.